# jQuery - How can I hide element B when I hover over element A?

Tags: jquery, hover, hide

I have two elements, and I need element B to be hidden on mouseover of element A. How would I do this with jQuery? My current code is this:

```
$(".rule").hover(function() {
            $(".jobDesc").hide();
        }
    );
```

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1.min, btw.

Comment: Any error you getting ?

Comment: No, it's just not hiding the jobDesc div when I hover over the rule div.

Comment: since you did not attach your HTML fragment, it is bit hard to tell. but there is one thing you can try. In the hover handler put console.info($(".jobDesc")); before calling hide. first check if anything print out in firefox or chrome console, if there is check if the the element print out is correct. If nothing print, check if you have any element matches this selector **.rule**, if it prints something like **null** or empty array **[]**, then go find if any element matches selector **.jobDesc**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call it on DOM ready , then it works for you

```
$(function (){
 $(".rule").hover(function() {
        $(".jobDesc").hide();
    }); 
})
```

here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pervez/Kvg8M/4/)